# Javac command not found

Tags: java, path, command-prompt

When I attempt to compile a Java program, it says that javac command is not recognized. I have appended the JDK directory link to the PATH so that it looks like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin
```

I have followed the guide and still the "javac" command cannot be recognized.

I use windows 10.

Comment: Close your command window and open a new one. Welcome, and good luck further. PS. try to install IntelliJ IDEA, its great for learning java in an "IDE"

Comment: I love IntelliJ, but I think that's beyond this beginner.  I would suggest surrounding that path with quotes, because the space between "Program" and "Files" might be a problem.

Comment: *"Please hear me out till the end."* ... We would be more inclined to if you got to the point more directly!  (I will help you by removing the waffle from your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Set path, classpath and JAVA_HOME in environment variable .